# Ajax Tab Container invisible

Tags: asp.net, ajax, tabcontainer

After a day of googling, I have to ask this... this question has been ask numerous times but few seem to have got the answer. Why does the tab container go Hidden on page load??
Does ANYONE have a solution to make/keep it visible??
I am using Toolkit Script Manager & I have laready tried removing the toolkit & adding again... My HTML code is Huge so cant post it... SO allows only 30000 Chars I guess...

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" CssClass="ajax__tab_lightblue-theme"
                    ActiveTabIndex="0" Visible="true" OnClientActiveTabChanged="ClientFunction">
                    <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="My Profile" ID="tbpnlMyProfile">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            My Profile
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <table style="width: 100%;">
```

Comment: never.... if its not visible on pageload when can it be visible... the page btw only has the tab container which then has other controls in it...

Comment: @AdityaNawandar just to be sure: it not visible due client-side `onload` event but after page completely loaded it becomes visible? Is this assumption right?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the OnClientActiveTabChanged event from the tab container. If the script does not exist, this can cause the container not to appear.

EDIT:

Ok, so I tried to get your code working. Of course it didn't work because you are using the asp: prefix instead of the ajaxToolkit: prefix. Try this:

```
<ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" CssClass="ajax__tab_lightblue-theme"
                ActiveTabIndex="0" Visible="true" OnClientActiveTabChanged="ClientFunction">
                <asp:ajaxToolkit runat="server" HeaderText="My Profile" ID="tbpnlMyProfile">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        My Profile
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:ajaxToolkit>
        </asp:ajaxToolkit>
```

EDIT:

Ok, last edit I promise. I still think its the OnClientActiveTabChanged event. When I remove that the tab shows up. When its there, the page is blank. Copy this and paste it:

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" CssClass="ajax__tab_lightblue-theme"
                ActiveTabIndex="0" Visible="true" >
                <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="My Profile" ID="tbpnlMyProfile">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        My Profile
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <table style="width: 100%;">
```